# How to get all user record after me from auth_user table order by date_joined in django [ closed ]

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models, sql-order-by

I'm new with django,

I just want to **get all user record** after a **specific username** from **auth_user** table order by date_joined.

Please guide or reply to your valuable response.

Thanks for all!

Comment: What do you mean with "after a specific username"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Like we generally use User.objects.all() for all user record but in my case, I just want to pass a username and fetch all record after that username from auth_user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, I found a trick, it's helpful for me.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def user_list_after_me(request):
    username = request.user.username

    user = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
    start_date = user.date_joined
    end_date = datetime.datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0)

    user_list = list(User.objects.filter(date_joined__range=[start_date, end_date]))

    messages.warning(request, str(start_date)+' || '+str(end_date))
    messages.warning(request, len(user_list))

    return render(request, 'list.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

It Work's For You!!

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth

def userList(request):

User.objects.filter(username=username).order_by('date_joined')
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not complete, I just want to pass an argument self. username and get all row/record after that username from the auth_user table.